# Decommissioning ECL items

Tags: web8.5, ecl, media-manager, ecl-connector

I am in the process of decommissioning Media Manager, so I have more than 50K ECL items in Tridion that should be unpublished, removed and MM connector removed.

Now I was wondering, is there any script provided by SDL that does just that? Something like publication remove. Something that will find and remove them all?

Or do I have to do it manually (by core service script)?

Comment: Maybe check directly with support; maybe you can offer a DB script that Support would be happy to validate and add to the armoury for others?

Comment: hhahahahhahah come on Mark, I want to be lazy... :D I don't want to make other people lazy :D

Comment: but yeah, script can be created. We are working on core service one... with unlocalize, unpublish and delete....

Comment: Just seems a lot of work for something that is most likely a one off and much simpler through the DB. But - with the functionality you have above I guess you could have this work for a few different scenarios anyway :)